# AWS Lambda connection times out due socket errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My AWS lambda connection keeps timing out due to socket errors. I have set out the timeout for the lambda to be 12 minutes in the code (EDIT: I mean in the lambda console) and the lambda is not in private vpc so the problem is not related to that.

For example: I run a function that runs 450 seconds. The function runs successfully in the AWS but it is above some magical threshold so the python code waits until the timeout and then throws an error. If the lambda runtime is less than the magical threshold then the python code works without any errors.

Might it be some kind of socket error that then loses the connection after some time but keeps waiting until the socket times out? I have no experience related to how sockets work in Ubuntu machines.

My code for testing:

Lambda code:

```
import json
from time import sleep

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("SLEEPING: " + str(event["sleep_time"]) + "s")
    sleep(event["sleep_time"])
    print("SLEEP ENDED")
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "sleep_time": event["sleep_time"]
    }
```

Code to invoke lambda:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
import json
from datetime import datetime

read_timeout = 500
connect_timeout = 500
sleep_time = 450
config = Config(
    read_timeout=read_timeout,
    connect_timeout=connect_timeout,
    retries={"max_attempts": 0}
)

lambda_client = boto3.client(
    "lambda",
    aws_access_key_id="xxx",
    aws_secret_access_key="xxx",
    config=config
)

st = datetime.now()
print(f"STARTED AT: {st}")
print(f"\tSLEEP TIME PARAMETER: {sleep_time}")
print(f"\tCONFIG read_timeout {read_timeout}")
print(f"\tCONFIG connect_timeout {connect_timeout}")
try:
    lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="helloWorld",
        Payload=json.dumps({"sleep_time": sleep_time})
    )
finally:
    et = datetime.now()
    print(f"ENDED AT: {et}")
    print(f"SECONDS TAKEN TO COMPLETE: {et - st}")
```

The function works when the sleep_time is set to low e.q. 3 but I keep running into errors when I set the sleep_time to larger values.

Output with sleep_time=3

```
STARTED AT: 2022-08-02 18:17:04.015493
    SLEEP TIME PARAMETER: 3
    CONFIG read_timeout 500
    CONFIG connect_timeout 500
ENDED AT: 2022-08-02 18:17:07.357435
SECONDS TAKEN TO COMPLETE: 0:00:03.341942
```

Output with longer sleeptime:

```
STARTED AT: 2022-08-02 19:03:36.196755
    SLEEP TIME PARAMETER: 450
    CONFIG read_timeout 500
    CONFIG connect_timeout 500
ENDED AT: 2022-08-02 19:11:56.553257
SECONDS TAKEN TO COMPLETE: 0:08:20.356502
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 277, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 448, in send
    urllib_response = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 376, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 423, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 330, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: AWSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=900)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/lambda_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    lambda_client.invoke(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 898, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 921, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 119, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 202, in _send_request
    while self._needs_retry(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 354, in _needs_retry
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 207, in __call__
    if self._checker(**checker_kwargs):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 284, in __call__
    should_retry = self._should_retry(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 320, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 363, in __call__
    checker_response = checker(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 247, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 416, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 281, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 377, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 485, in send
    raise ReadTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/helloWorld/invocations"
```

Edit:

Cloudwatch log for the errorcase:

```
2022-08-02T19:03:36.526+03:00   START RequestId: feffa401-62a2-4c77-8a92-96be27bdceeb Version: $LATEST

2022-08-02T19:03:36.529+03:00   SLEEPING: 450s

2022-08-02T19:11:06.638+03:00   SLEEP ENDED

2022-08-02T19:11:06.640+03:00   END RequestId: feffa401-62a2-4c77-8a92-96be27bdceeb

2022-08-02T19:11:06.640+03:00   REPORT RequestId: feffa401-62a2-4c77-8a92-96be27bdceeb Duration: 450102.24 ms Billed Duration: 450103 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 37 MB
```

The one that succeeded is similar to this

Comment: How have you "set out the timeout for the lambda to be 12 minutes in the code"? The Lambda function timeout is a configuration value. The CloudWatch logs are important here so review them. And read [How do I troubleshoot Lambda function invocation timeout errors?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-troubleshoot-invocation-timeouts/)

Comment: Hi I meant in the cloudwatch console. Edited my answer. I appended the cloudwatch logs, it seems there is no error. The lambda keeps running, returns value after 450 seconds but the socket dies out and waits until the timeout.